# What does lozärner mean?

Tags: pronunciation, pronoun, swiss-standard-german, swiss-german

There's a word that's spelled as "Lüzerner", but what is lozärner supposed to mean and how is it different?

How is their pronunciation different?

Comment: Could you specify the context in which you encountered that word?

Comment: Neither is a word in standard German, so it needs explanation, at least from a context. If you see it spellt like that, it is written, so linking or citing the source will go a great length.

Comment: Why don't you think that this means Luzerner? I'm confused

Comment: These comments were unproductive. It's a straight-forward question, if either you know of the word or not. Best answer has been chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you didn't provide context or a source, so this is pretty much just a guess. *Lozärn* is a Swiss German spelling of Luzern/Lucerne, the city in central Switzerland. The *-er* suffix means related to, taking place in, or coming from. So *Lozärner* describes something/someone related to, taking place in, or coming from Lucerne. YouTube has several videos related to the Lucerne Carnival, which is apparently called *Lozärner Fasnacht* in the local dialect. German hasn't always capitalized adjectives formed using *-er* from proper nouns, so it's probably possible to see it spelled *lozärner*. Being dialect, you won't find the word in dictionaries of Standard German, but you can find both [Lozärn](https://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzern) and [Lozärner Fasnacht](https://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzerner_Fasnacht) in the Alemannic German edition of Wikipedia.

Comment: But there's already the word Luzerner, why 2 spellings? And pronunciation?

Comment: @user610620: Swiss German isn't the same as Standard German. It's a collection of related dialects, and spelling and vocabulary differ from not only from Standard German, but differ from region to region within Switzerland, The differences between American and British English are minor in comparison, but American "color" differs from British "colour" and an American "elevator" is a British "lift". I can't tell you much about pronunciation, and it would pronounced differently in different regions anyway. See my answer to your previous question for more information.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Luzerner is Standard German? And Lözarner is Swiss German? If so, is there a source for that. (And does that mean the city of Lucerne is spelled Lözarn by Swiss germans, and Luzern by High Germans?) Would like to know the differences for each peoples per canton eventually.

Comment: @user610620: Luzerner is Standard German, Lözarner *a* spelling in Swiss German. As I mentioned in the other answer, Swiss German does not really have standardized spelling, and there are variations in spelling between dialects. Dialects aren't organized neatly by Canton, though Canton names are used to group them. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannic_German) for a partial list of dialects. No one really knows even how many dialects there are.

Comment: @user610620: You seem to be looking for information that this site does not have to offer. As I mentioned in my previous answer, I'm not an expert and am getting what little information I have from other places on the internet. Most of the regulars here are from Germany or Austria, so they wouldn't know any more about Swiss German than a typical American would know about the many dialects/accents of northern England.

Comment: Thanks everyone for sharing your knowledge of Swiss-German, a very interesting topic and tag. But hope someone could clarify one question earlier in the comments: Do the Swiss spell the city Lucerne as "Lözarn"? Living in Switzerland, I've never seen it crop up, only Luzern (standard German). If this is a different spelling of the actual city name (besides the pronoun Lözarner), then does Genf (Geneva) also have a Swiss-German spelling?

Comment: @user610620 although this is an old question: "Lozärn" is just one way to spell Luzern in Swiss-German, from personal experience it's mostly people from Luzern who spell it like that, people from Bern (city) would mostly use "Luzärn". And yes, every Swiss-German word has multiple spellings since Swiss-German doesn't have one standardised set of spellings.

Comment: This makes Swiss-German somewhat unique because instead of having words we just write however we would pronounce the words, this can make learning to read it quite hard since you can't learn vocabulary, instead you have to learn to understand and speak it before you can read it. As for your example of Genf, I, as someone from Bern, would write "Gänf".

Comment: Could you link Luzerner-specific instruction books?